# form action url change depending on #tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to change a forms action Url with jQuery/js depending on a browser #tag?

The tabs are working correctly I just need the action to change as well.

Here is the tab js I am currently using, I am also using the jQuery Address Plugin also:

```
var QTABS = {

init: function () {
    // attached onload and change event to address plugin
    $.address.init(function(event) {
        // first load, set panel
        QTABS.setPanel(event);
    }).change(function(event) {
        // if the url changes, set panel
        QTABS.setPanel(event);          
    });
},

// the core function to display correct panel
setPanel: function (event) {

    // grab the hash tag from address plugin event
    var hashtag = event.pathNames[0];
    // get the correct tab item, if no hashtag, get the first tab item
    var tab = (hashtag) ? $('.tabs li a[href=#' + hashtag + ']') : $('.tabs li:first a');

    // reset everything to default
    $('.tabs li').removeClass('activeTab');
    $('.tab_container .tab_content').hide();

    // if hashtag is found
    if (hashtag) {

        // set current tab item active and display correct panel
        tab.parent().addClass('activeTab');
        $('.tab_container .tab_content:eq(' + (tab.parent().index()) + ')').show();          

    } else {

        // set the first tab item and first panel               
        $('.tabs li:first').addClass('activeTab');
        $('.tab_container .tab_content:first').show();           

    }

    if ($('.tabs').length)
    {
        // change the page title to current selected tab
        document.title = tab.attr('title');
    }
}
}

// Execute this script!
QTABS.init();
```

Comment: I can't see where's the problem - if your code works, you can easily add another function to `init` and `change` functions. In your new function make use of event object wich contains hashtag and set form action as necessary, for example like this: `$("#form").attr('action', hashtag_or_something);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ahve used successfully

```
  $("#myDelete").click(function(){
       $('#myForm').attr("action", "accounttrandelete.php"); 
      $("#myForm").submit();
      return false;
    });
  $("#myEdit").click(function(){
      $('#myForm').attr("action", "accounttranedit.php"); 
      $("#myForm").submit();
      return false;
    });
  $("#myRec").click(function(){
      $('#myForm').attr("action", "accounttranrec.php"); 
      $("#myForm").submit();
      return false;
    });
  $("#myUnRec").click(function(){
      $('#myForm').attr("action", "accounttranunrec.php"); 
      $("#myForm").submit();
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I don't know where the form is and how you want to access it. If you want change the action url to do this:

```
$("form").attr("action", "Put your new Url here");
```

**UPDATE**:

```
$("#tag")..attr("action", "Put your new Url here");
```

If you want to use standard Javascript you can change as follow:

```
document.forms[0].action = "Put your new Url here";
```

Note: you can replace `forms[0]` by the name of your form.

**UPDATE:**

If you have a form with an id then its similar to above method call:

```
document.getElementById("tag").action = "Put your new Url here";
```

Comment: thanks for your response, I want append to the url with a #tag

Comment: @neoszion Preventing a missunderstanding, do you meant with '#tag' that your form has got an id attribute?